# Which operators will cause an Observable to evaluate?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactivex

I am working with `rxjs` in particular, but I am asking about ReactiveX in general.

There are many mentions that `Oberservable` are lazily evaluated, but searching through [the docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html), I cannot find explicit mention of which operators will cause an `Observable` to be evaluated. The only operator I know of that will cause evaluation is `subscribe`. Are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the only operator you need. In order to trigger an Observable, you need to subscribe to it. No need to do anything with the results, you only need to subscribe:

```
functionThatReturnsAnObservable().subscribe(function(data){});
```

**Edit**
As cartant said, there are functions that implicitly invoke the subscribe operator, such as the `forEach` and `toPromise` functions.

Comment: For completeness, you might want to mention that methods like [`forEach`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Observable.ts#L225-L272) and [`toPromise`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/Observable.ts#L330-L354) exist on `Observable.prototype` and involve implicit calls to `subscribe`. And before pipeable operators came along, [`toPromise`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.3/src/operator/toPromise.ts) was an operator.

Comment: Does map actually cause evaluation? I have had situations where I used map on an observable, and nothing was actually evaluated until I subscribed to the result of the map.

Comment: Maybe it does evaluate,  i've only used it to manipulate date before subscribing to them.